# In Angular Slick grid Multi select field is not able to filter

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I am using angular slick grid 2.25.1 Version and I Have migrated this version from 2.19.0. I have fixed the compilation error while building the application.

Migration Steps followed.

1. Changed Angular slick grid version 2.19.0 to 2.25.1.
2. NPM installed with Updated Package JSON.
3. Changed the toggle enable and disable code.

While clicking the toggle filter I am getting this error.

screenshot.

[image]

Environment Setup:

- Angular: 7.3.5
- NPM: 6.9.0
- ionic: 4.12.0
- codova: 8.0.0

Comment: Your question is not complete, to be a valid Stack Overflow question it should have much more info than that. On another side, every single version of Angular-Slickgrid are tested with prod build with [angular-slickgrid-demos](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid-demos), so you should refer to that instead

Comment: on a side note, you're using an Angular version that is no longer supported by Angular themselves... on their website they say "Angular versions v4, v5, v6, v7, and v8 are no longer under support." and Angular 9 LTS ends Aug 06, 2021. So you might want to upgrade that too. There is nothing wrong with the Angular-Slickgrid lib, because like I said I run prod build on every single release on my GitHub demo projects (I run BS3 and BS4 prod build on every single release I do)